# How to pass an EditText Value from a method to Insert function for SQLiteOpenHelper class in same Activity?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-sqlite

I have a spinner that chooses branch values and stores in EditText in onItemSelected Method. But I need the value displayed in edit Text ( branch) to be assigned previously to SqliteDatabase Insertion operation Method in same activity. Sorry I couldn't frame question appropriately.

register.java

```
public class register extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {


    SQLiteOpenHelper openHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Button _btnsignup;
    EditText _txtFname, _txtLname, _txtpass, _txtemail, _txtrollno;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);

        openHelper=new DatabaseHelper(this);

        _btnsignup= findViewById(R.id.btn_signup);
        _txtFname=findViewById(R.id.fname);
        _txtLname=findViewById(R.id.lname);
        _txtpass=findViewById(R.id.password);
        _txtemail=findViewById(R.id.email);
        _txtrollno=findViewById(R.id.rollno);
        _btnsignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                db=openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                String fname=_txtFname.getText().toString();
                String Lname= _txtLname.getText().toString();
                String pwd= _txtpass.getText().toString();
                String email= _txtemail.getText().toString();
                String rollno= _txtrollno.getText().toString();

                insertdata(Fname, Lname, pwd,email,rollno);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registered Succesfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        Spinner spinner=findViewById(R.id.semester);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.semester,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

public void insertdata( String Fname, String Lname, String pwd, String email, String rollno){
    ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COL_2, Fname);
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COL_3, Lname);
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COL_4, pwd);
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COL_5, email);
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COL_6, rollno);
    long id=db.insert(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        String text=adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
        EditText branch= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.branch);
        String text2=adapterView.getSelectedItem().toString();
        branch.setText(text2);
        Toast.makeText(adapterView.getContext(),text,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }


    public void open_login(View view){
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),login.class));
    }
}
```

I need to pass the Editext value from `branch.setText(text2);` to `String branch= _txtbranch.getText().toString();` defined above in `public void onclick`. But it says cannot

> Resolve symbol branch.getText().toString; since its declared in another function.

If I declare it globally then the `getItemSlelected` Method shows error and app crashes. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest the following changes :-

- Declaring spinner, adapter and _txtbranch as class variables
- Setting the Views (spinner and _txtbranch) along with the other views
- Optionally not having an Overrride for onItemSelected or onNothingSelected but to instead retrieve the selected item in the button's onclick (so no need for the branch EditText).

The following code includes the above, but see comments :-

```
public class register extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    SQLiteOpenHelper openHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Button _btnsignup;
    Spinner spinner; //<<<<<<<<<< DECLARED HERE
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter; //<<<<<<<<<< DECLARED HERE
    EditText _txtFname, _txtLname, _txtpass, _txtemail, _txtrollno, _txtbranch /* <<<<<<<<<< CHANGED  to add _txtbranch>>>>>>>> */;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);
        openHelper=new DatabaseHelper(this);

        _btnsignup= findViewById(R.id.btn_signup);
        _txtFname=findViewById(R.id.fname);
        _txtLname=findViewById(R.id.lname);
        _txtpass=findViewById(R.id.password);
        _txtemail=findViewById(R.id.email);
        _txtrollno=findViewById(R.id.rollno);
        _txtbranch=findViewById(R.id.branch); /* <<<<<<<<<< ADDED >>>>>>>>>> Alternately not needed if getting item directly from spinner*/
        spinner=findViewById(R.id.semester); /*<<<<<<<<<<< MOVED TO HERE spinner defined as a class variable */

        _btnsignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                db=openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                String fname=_txtFname.getText().toString();
                String Lname= _txtLname.getText().toString();
                String pwd= _txtpass.getText().toString();
                String email= _txtemail.getText().toString();
                String rollno= _txtrollno.getText().toString();
                String branch = _txtbranch.getText().toString(); // code wanted BUT not needed if value obtained directly from the spinner
                //String branch = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString(); // ALTERNATIVE no need  _txtbranch duplicating selected value

                insertdata(Fname, Lname, pwd,email,rollno);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registered Succesfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"Registered Succesfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // Alternative to previous line gets the context from the view
            }
        });

        adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.semester,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item); //<<<<<<<<<< CHANGED
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this); //<<<<<<<<<< not really needed as selected item can be retrieved directly from spinner
    }

    public void insertdata( String Fname, String Lname, String pwd, String email, String rollno) {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COL_2, Fname);
        contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COL_3, Lname);
        contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COL_4, pwd);
        contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COL_5, email);
        contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COL_6, rollno);
        long id = db.insert(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    }

    // Not needed if retrieving value directly from spinner
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

        String text=adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
        //branch= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.branch);
        String text2=adapterView.getSelectedItem().toString();
        _txtbranch.setText(text2);
        Toast.makeText(adapterView.getContext(),text,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    // Not needed if retrieving value directly from spinner
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }

    public void open_login(View view){
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),login.class));
    }
}
```

- **Note** the above is in-principle code, it has not been run or tested and my therefore contain some errors.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try it out.